# Apple's Reachability without ARC

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, automatic-ref-counting

I want to check Internet connection in my app. So i use Apple's Reachability sample code.

But because of using ARC there are some errors. I correct some of them but other errors still in my code.

[image]

How should i solve this problems? Any ideas?

Thnx.

Comment: Try to make ARC disable. [look this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project) modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this for your ARC version code -> [Reachability (iOS) ARCified](https://gist.github.com/1182373)

Comment: This is a poor reason to maintain your own fork of Apple's sample code when `-fno-objc-arc` is available.

Comment: Yes I too feel the same after coming to know that ARC can be disabled :(

Answer (score 22):

You can disable ARC on a per-file basis.

1. Select the project in the file list
2. Select the target
3. Click the Build Phases tab
4. Open the Compile Sources phase
5. Scroll down until you find your source file (or use the search field)
6. Double-click in the Compiler Flags column for that file
7. Enter `-fno-objc-arc`

Now ARC is disabled for that one file.

Comment: sorry, that's not an option =) i need ARC

Comment: setting this flag will not disable ARC for all of the project, but just the flagged files